# Android : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android

I import a .jar according to these steps:

1. under folder **libs** into you project root folder, I Copy my Jar files in this folder
2. and right click on the Jar file and then select **Build Path > Add to Build Path**.

The jar appears under Android dependencies.

But i have this error :
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mypackage.MyClass**

Please help me. I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: Add it to  classpath is should work , please update full stack trace in posts@Alberto Alberto

Comment: right click on the project - properties - java build path - Order and export - tick Android private libraries and all the libraries that u added

Answer (score 1):

If you are compiling your JAR in a different system, you are probably using a different JRE.
try javac -version on both computers, and if they are differents, you can fix it focing the target JRE, like:

```
javac -target 1.6 -source 1.6 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have to add it to the "Order and Export" tab on the Build path.
Right click your project -> build path -> configure build path (assuming you're coding on eclipse.

Comment: I tried [this solution](http://androidandeclipse.blogspot.fr/2012/11/referenced-projects-and.html). It doesn't work. Here some images of my project : [package explorer](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cnmdlklknawqbq3/jar_project.PNG), [java build path](https://www.dropbox.com/s/87qhvquuu1w567e/order_export.PNG)